# Convert a Decimal number to float and truncate it

Tags: javascript, floating-point, decimal

I have a number

For example:

```
8183
```

What I need is to convert it to a float number-

For example 8183

```
(8183).toFixed(2);
```

will return me

```
8183.00
```

But I need to truncate it further, so the final number will be

```
8.18
```

So basically I need to make it float number with just 2 decimal places.
I tried using the Math.floor and ceil but couldnt figure it out!

Comment: Can you just divide by 1000? Your 3rd and 4th steps have different magnitudes, so this is no longer truncation/rounding, which makes your goal confusing.

Comment: How can 8183 identified as 8.18?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well what you're trying to accomplish is not completely clear, but I think that if you start by dividing by 1000, then call `toFixed` on it, it will give you the desired result.

```
var before = 8183;
var after = (before / 1000).toFixed(2); //8.18
```

Comment: +1 as I was just about to post the same. 8183 is a completely different number than 8.xx as such you have to most likely resort to division to move the decimal point across.

Comment: +1, also what I was going to post. However, check your result, you've made a mistake: `//8.81` should be `//8.18`

Answer (score 4):

You could divide by 10 until you are less than 10:

```
var digits = 8183;
while((digits = digits/10) > 10) {}
digits = digits.toFixed(2); // 8.18
```

For negative numbers, you could want to store a boolean value and use `Math.abs(digits)`.

For numbers less than 0, you would want to multiple instead of divide.

---

If all you really want is scientific notation use [toExponential(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential)